# C# regex that matches a line of only whitespace

Tags: c#

I want to check if a `\n` terminated `string` contains only whitespace. I unsuccessfully tried with the following regular expression:

```
new Regex(@"\s*\n")
```

Comment: Usually in regular expressions, '^' is used to match the start of a line, and '$' to match the end of the line. I don't know whether that's the case for C#'s Regex as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `^` and `$` to denote the beginning and the end of the line, as follows:

```
^\s*$
```

Note that in addition to lines consisting of only whitespace characters, this expression will also match empty lines; if this is not desirable, replace `*` with a `+`.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
if (yourString.Trim() == ""){
 //just whitespace
}
```

Or, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString)`

Comment: +1 - a non-regex solution should always be preferred if possible